# Populate Spinner based on Selection ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I am using same String `array` to populate data into **two spinners**, like this:

```
String[] arrayMonths = { "January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May",
        "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November","December" };

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayMonths);

spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, I want whenever i make selection in spinner1, like i have selected `August` then show `September` as initial value in spinner2 (And also **remove** all the `previous months` in **spinner2**).

In a same way, if i selected **October** in `spinner1`, then start `spinner2` with **November**

```
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        spinner1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
```

**UPDATE -** As suggested by @AMY

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;   

    String newArr[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        final String[] arrayMonths = { "January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May",
        "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November","December" };

        newArr = new String[] {"January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May",
                "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November","December"};

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayMonths);

        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        spinner1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                newArr = new String[arrayMonths.length-1];
                System.arraycopy(arrayMonths , position, newArr , 0, arrayMonths.length);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newArr);
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Getting Exception:** `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=12 srcPos=0 dst.length=11 dstPos=0 length=12
```

Comment: try setting `spinner2.setSelection((position+1)%12);`

Comment: you just want to show selection or want to remove previous month items?

Comment: @Amy i also want to remove previous month items, post your solution

Comment: @Oreo Please check posted answer

Comment: @Oreo checkout my answer hope this is what you want.

Comment: you didn't initialize newArr –

Comment: `System.arraycopy(arrayMonths , position, newArr , 0, arrayMonths arrayMonths.length);` add this line also

Comment: `newArr = new String[arrayMonths.length-1];`creates an array of the length of 11 and you copy an array into it of the length of 12. What did you try to achieve with this -1?

Comment: I think that you are overcomplicating things. You will need two of these arrays of course. (get rid of the -1 on copying them) and you will have to use two different adapters. Unfortunately I cannto help much now but may be able to doing so in the evening. (8 hours from now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code at these lines :

```
newArr = new String[arrayMonths.length]; 
System.arraycopy(arrayMonths, position, newArr, 0, arrayMonths.length);
```

You need to define the array size as **arrayMonths.length - (selected_position+1)**.

Moreover, Check the Signature of method *arraycopy* :

> src : the source array to copy the content.
>
> srcPos : the starting
>   index of the content in src.
>
> dst : the destination array to copy the data into.
>
> dstPos : the starting index for the copied content in dst.
>
> length : the number of elements to be copied.

So, you need to change the length of elements to be copied as *arrayMonths.length-selected_position*.

## Code snippet

```
int nextPosition = position + 1;
int newSize= arrayMonths.length-nextPosition ;
newArr = new String[newSize]; 
System.arraycopy(arrayMonths, nextPosition , newArr, 0, newSize);
```

Hope it helps you ツ

Comment: hi i need a small change, i don't want to show december in spinner1 and january in spinner2..

Answer (score 1):

`OnItemSelect` copy the your months array from selected postion to last position in new array. And set that new array to snd `Spinner`

```
     spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                      String[] newArr = new String[arrayMonths.length-1];
                      System.arraycopy(arrayMonths , position, newArr , 0, arrayMonths.length);
                      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newArr);
                      spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
                      spinner2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

Comment: checked, getting:  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=12 srcPos=0 dst.length=0 dstPos=0 length=12

Comment: @Oreo its just way how to do it..you should improve code as per your need :)

Comment: you didn't initialize newArr

Comment: I initialized and posted updated code above check, still getting: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=12 srcPos=0 dst.length=11 dstPos=0 length=12

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that :
In your `Spinner1's` onItemSelected method you can write like below

```
spinner2.setSelection(position+1);
```

here you make sure that if the `index` is last it will throw a `IndexOutOfBoundExcecption` so handle that.

Answer (score 0):

On your spinner1:

```
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
               if(position<arrayMonths.length-1){
                   spinner2.setSelection(position+1)
                }
                else{
                    //set spinner 2 selection to january if spinner1 selects december.
                   spinner2.setSelection(0);
                 }
            }
       }
```

Comment: I checked your solution, but i also want to remove previous month item in spinner2

Comment: like when you select items on spinner 2, you'll change the month on spinner 1 also? ex. If i select january on spinner 1 then spinner 2 becomes february and when i select march on spinner2 then spinner 1 becomes february?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                spinner2.setSelection((position + 1) % 12);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position>0) {
                    spinner1.setSelection((position - 1) % 12);
                }else{
                    spinner1.setSelection(11);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```